# Sentence Transformers no more on HuggingFace?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers, huggingface-hub

I'm trying to download Sentence Transformer but they seem to have been wiped from HuggingFace. Does anyone know why ?

https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers

Comment: It is an temproary issue. [Hf is already working on it](https://twitter.com/huggingface/status/1655760648926642178?s=20). Models will be back sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an error on HuggingFace. It's back again. Here the POST-MORTEM

> Through a combination of human error and technical issues, the Hugging Face Hub was experiencing some intermittent difficulties today for ~12 hours, and about 250 users and organizations were incorrectly displayed as deleted, which led to downtime for some great downstream libraries like sentence-transformers. (Nils Reimers)

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same thing, all of the sentence-transformers just went missing from the site.  You can download them from sbert directly (they have downloadable list of models at

https://public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reimers/sentence-transformers/v0.2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem,

As a work around I'm using: `obrizum/all-MiniLM-L6-v2`

This model gives the same embeddings as the sentence transformers `all-MiniLM-L6-v2`

[link to the model](https://huggingface.co/obrizum/all-MiniLM-L6-v2)