# all-MiniLM-L6-v2 no longer available, any ideas?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, topic-modeling

What happened to some sentence transformers on Hugging Face? Why is all-MiniLM-L6-v2 not available anymore? I want to use it in the BERTopic model but I cannot. Are there any alternative embedding techniques which do not require logining into the Hugging Face.

404 error page appears.

https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2

Error: is not a valid model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

I tried to use it as the default embedding technique in BERTopic but it fails to run.

Comment: It is an temproary issue. [Hf is already working on it](https://twitter.com/huggingface/status/1655760648926642178?s=20). Models will be back sooner or later.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Sentence Transformers no more on HuggingFace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205193/sentence-transformers-no-more-on-huggingface)